# How do I use colorbox to show hidden divs on my page without hardcoding?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, colorbox

I'm using Colorbox to show the html content of hidden divs on my page.  I can get this to work perfectly with the following:

```
$("a.colorbox").colorbox({width:"600px", inline:true, href:"#344"});
```

This will show the div with the ID of 344.

However, because I'm trying to build a scalable and dynamic page with WordPress, I want to be able to grab the ID of my divs through a function, rather than hard code them in the jquery call.

I modified Jack Moore's example:

```
$("a[rel='example']").colorbox({title: function(){
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    return '<a href="'+url+'" target="_blank">Open In New Window</a>';
}});
```

so that it looks like this:

```
$(".colorbox").colorbox({width:"600px", inline:true, href:function(){
    var elementID = $(this).attr('id');
    return elementID;
}});
```

The problem with this is that the href property of the colorbox function is looking for a string with a # mark infront of the ID.  I tried various ways of concatenating the # to the front of the function, including the # in the return value, and concatenating the # to the elementID variable.  No luck.

I also tried using the syntax in Jack's example (with no luck) so that my return statement looked like this:

```
return "#'+elementID+'";
```

I think my basic question is: How do I use colorbox to show hidden divs on my page without hardcoding everything?

Thanks for your help,
Jiert

Comment: My first thought is that wouldn't `return "#'+elementID+'"` return a string? Perhaps `return "#" + elementID;` would be closer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
return "#" + elementID;
```

will have the desired effect as David says.

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for advice on how to format your answers, so that code *looks* like code, for example. +1, by the way (in a shameless act of self-celebration...) =)

Comment: Awesome, thanks folks!  That does indeed work. Appreciate it :D

Comment: Can you share your css/html that went with the jQuery? I'm having a similar problem...what did it look like?

Answer (score 7):

I didn't really like any of the answers given above. This is how I did it (similar but not quite the same).
I also fully commented it for people a bit new to Javascript and the colorbox plug in.

```
$(document).ready(function() { //waits until the DOM has finished loading
    if ($('a.lightboxTrigger').length){ //checks to see if there is a lightbox trigger on the page
        $('a.lightboxTrigger').each(function(){ //for every lightbox trigger on the page...
            var url = $(this).attr("href"); // sets the link url as the target div of the lightbox
            $(url).hide(); //hides the lightbox content div
            $(this).colorbox({
                 inline:true, // so it knows that it's looking for an internal href
                 href:url, // tells it which content to show
                 width:"70%",
                 onOpen:function(){ //triggers a callback when the lightbox opens
                    $(url).show(); //when the lightbox opens, show the content div
                 },
                 onCleanup:function(){
                    $(url).hide(); //hides the content div when the lightbox closes
                 }
            }).attr("href","javascript:void(0)"); //swaps the href out with a javascript:void(0) after it's saved the href to the url variable to stop the browser doing anything with the link other than launching the lightbox when clicked
              //you could also use "return false" for the same effect but I proffered that way
        })
     }
});
```

And this is the html:

```
<a class="lightboxTrigger" href="#lightboxContent">Lightbox trigger</a>
<div id="lightboxContent" class="lightboxContent"> <!-- the class is just to make it easier to style with css if you have multiple lightboxes on the same page -->
     <p>Lightbox content goes here</p>
</div>
```

I think it would work with multiple lightboxes on the one page but I haven't tested it with that.

Comment: It was very helpful that you documented the 'inline' option! I'd add that if you put your target inside of a hidden div you can forego the onOpen and onCleanup steps shown here.

Comment: Good point. :) I wrote this when I was still a bit inexperienced.

Answer (score 6):

I'm facing the same issue. What does your html look like? meaning, how did you structure your "divs"

Mine looks like this:
Javascript:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("a.colorbox").colorbox({ width: "50%", inline: true, href: function () {
          var elementID = $(this).attr('id');
          return "#" + elementID;
       } 
      }); 
    });
</script>
```

And the html looks like (I tried changing the display:none):

```
<a class='colorbox' href="#">Inline HTML</a>
   <div style="display:none">
       <div id="pop">
          This data is to be displayed in colorbox
       </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: You need to set the href of your .colorbox link to #pop like:

Comment: <pre><a class='colorbox' href="#pop">Inline HTML</a>
   <div style="display:none">
       <div id="pop">
          This data is to be displayed in colorbox
       </div>
   </div></pre>

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I got it to work

**HTML: (taken from the example in one of the answers)**

```
<a class="lightboxTrigger" href="#lightboxContent">Lightbox trigger</a>
<div id="lightboxContent" class="lightboxContent"> <!-- the class is just to make it easier to style with css if you have multiple lightboxes on the same page -->
     <p>Lightbox content goes here</p>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('a.lightboxTrigger').click(function(){ 
    var ref = $(this).attr("href");
    $.colorbox({ html: $(ref).html() });
    $.colorbox.resize();
 });
```